# Connecting Multiple Big Stepper Motors to RPi

Tags: driver

I am fairly new to using stepper motors and RPis, so have some potentially naive questions.

Firstly, I am using two [NEMA 34 stepper motors](https://www.omc-stepperonline.com/nema-34-stepper-motor/economic-nema-34-stepper-motor-bipolar-1-8deg-8-2-nm-1161-45oz-in-6-0a-86x86x114mm-4-wires.html) and planning to connect them with [DM860T drivers](https://www.omc-stepperonline.com/digital-stepper-driver-24-72a-18-80vac-or-36-110vdc-for-nema-34-motor-dm860t.html). However, I am unsure if I am able to connect these two, big drivers to a single RPi, or will I need two Rpis. Is this possible? Can a RPi work with these?

Any other assistance or advice will be greatly appreciated.

Thank you most kindly for your help.

Comment: Ah, my answer to this Q&A might help: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/561492/driving-step-motors-using-microstep-drivers-with-teensy-4. Cheers.

Comment: Your can skim AliEx catalog to pick your driver: (1) AliExpress Microstepper Catalog
https://www.aliexpress.com/w/wholesale-microstep%20driver.html

Comment: My humble DM542 can only do 4A. His big brother ***DM556S can do 6A***: (2) DM556 - AliExpress
https://fr.aliexpress.com/item/10000044779237.html?spm=a2g0o.search0302.0.0.1fdc31cacVMqlP&algo_pvid=0eecc53d-eb71-44d4-9b97-dbcf8e37baec&algo_expid=0eecc53d-eb71-44d4-9b97-dbcf8e37baec-17&btsid=0bb0624116193440268344558e2877&ws_ab_test=searchweb0_0,searchweb201602_,searchweb201603_. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

The Pi's logic (GPIO) outputs are 3V3.

You will not be able to drive the DM860T directly from the Pi's GPIO as the DM860T needs a minimum logic level of 4V.

To use the Pi with the DM860T you would need to add additional components to the Pi, e.g. transistors.